# AppArmor deny execution with "no new privs" when NoNewPrivileges=no

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, systemd, apparmor

After trying to confine my Python application I've been hitting these AppArmor messages

```
[ 1808.635237] audit: type=1400 audit(1600600443.250:50): apparmor="DENIED" operation="exec"
info="no new privs" error=-1 profile="/var/www/localhost/fastcgi/api.py"
name="/usr/bin/python3" pid=5672 comm="api" requested_mask="x" denied_mask="x" fsuid=42 ouid=0
```

With this profile (generated by aa-logprog)

```
#include <tunables/global>

profile /var/www/localhost/fastcgi/api.py flags=(attach_disconnected) {
  #include <abstractions/base>

  # Python:
  /usr/bin/python3{,.[7-9]} Cx,

  ^/usr/bin/python3{,.[7-9]} flags=(attach_disconnected) {
    #include <abstractions/base>

    /usr/bin/python3{,.[7-9]} mr,
  }
}
```

`Api` is systemd service. After reading this [post](https://apparmor.narkive.com/gz6XOZ39/avc-apparmor-allowed-operation-exec-info-no-new-privs-error-1) i noticed that `api.service` really has `NoNewPrivileges=yes` set. So I changed it to `NoNewPrivileges=no` (and reloaded the service) but that did not change a thing. The behavior is still exactly the same.

> yes once a task is under no new privs it is not allowed change its profile
> and potentially increase its privileges. There is one exception which is
> the unconfined state, since any profile transition is a reduction of
> privileges.
> So you are left with two potential transitions at the moment ix (inherit
> the current confinement) and stacking. Stacking is probably not what
> you want in that it keeps the current confinement and adds additional
> restrictions on top.

Any idea what else can cause `info="no new privs"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/18914

> ProtectHostname=yes appears to imply NoNewPrivileges=yes